# Underscore return all objects from nested array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Hi basic question I'm struggling with

```
var objs = [ {name:'obj_1', evidence:[2] }, {name:'obj_2', evidence[1] } ]
```

I'd like to return an array of all 3 evidence objects

What I have so far is

```
_.filter(objs, function(obj) { 
  if (obj.evidence.length > 0) {
    _.each(obj, function(x) { return x }) 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`_.pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) to reduce the array of objects to an array of a given property:

```
_.pluck(objs, 'evidence');

[ [2], [1] ]
```

If you wanted to flatten out the array, you could use "flatten":

```
_.flatten(_.pluck(objs, 'evidence'));

[2, 1]
```